# Python Tkinter checkbutton widget in MacOS: how do I set the text colour

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm struggling to find a way to change the foreground colour for the checkbutton widget for Tkinter on Mac. This is what I've tried. The foreground colour will always be white no matter what colour i choose.
`cbType = Checkbutton(root, text='Series?', background='#d9d9d9', fg='black', width='9').place(x=120, y=199)`
I assume this is an issue with Mac and not Tkinter or Python but if anyone has a fix even if it's importing a plugin like how tkmacosx fixes buttons for mac.

Comment: Are you looking for `selectcolor="black"`?

Comment: @TheLizzard This didn't seem to work unfortunately, thanks for the quick response though!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to change?

Comment: Specially just the text colour of 'Series?'

Comment: When I use `tk.Checkbutton(root, text='Series?', background='black', fg='white', activebackground="black", selectcolor="black")` I get a dark mode version of the normal `Checkbutton` (white text+check mark everything else is black). What do you get?

Comment: I guess it makes sense to just stick to the white text if nothing else works, this works great. I'm relatively new to stackoverflow, is there a way to mark comments as correct answers? Or what would I do.

Comment: I posted it as an answer. To mark it as correct (if it was what you were looking for) click on the check mark bellow the down triangle on the left of my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
tk.Checkbutton(root, text='Series?', background='black', fg="red", activebackground="black", selectcolor="black")
```

It should create a checkbutton that has red text and red check mark but everything else is black. Try changing the colours around.